# How to set expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources

Tags: pagespeed, static-content

I have read question related to this on stake, but all questions are different. We are only talking about static resource. Please see the image clearly ,then i request you to answer my question , because in our image only static components [page speed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdaJY.jpg) are there.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide some example code and state your problem a little better.

Answer (score 0):

How are you serving the static resources?  This will determine entirely how you can set the value.

In nginx, you would use the [`expires` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires).  In Apache, you would use the [`mod_expires` plugin](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html).  If you are using some third-party static asset serving service, like a CDN, you'll need to look up the documentation for that service to figure out how to set the appropriate cache headers.